# how to extract all sublists from nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have a nested list. For example:

```
['a', ['b', 'c', ['e', 'd']]]
```

I want to get a list which contains that list and all sublists separately as elements. So the expected results is:

```
[['a', ['b', 'c', ['e', 'd']]], ['b', 'c', ['e', 'd']], ['e', 'd']]
```

i wrote this function:

```
def extract(lst):
    result = []
    result.append(lst)
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            result.append(i)
            extractt(i)
    return result
```

But the result is not what expected. how could i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_lists(d):
  if isinstance(d, list):
     yield d
     for i in d:
        yield from get_lists(i)

print(list(get_lists(['a', ['b', 'c', ['e', 'd']]])))
```

Output:

```
[['a', ['b', 'c', ['e', 'd']]], ['b', 'c', ['e', 'd']], ['e', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code discards the result of the recursive call to `extract`. You could amend it like so:

```
def extract(lst):
    result = [lst]
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            result += extract(i)
    return result
```